# How to modify URL using .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a project using PHP. And, my files are properly organize to prevent confusion and keep it clean. Because of that I have a long URL because it has many directory.

I want to shorten the long URL to look clean. I didn't use any framework here. I just organized them by myself.

I have this URL on every views file (this URL is obviously for `home`):

```
tactical_trading/websites/toolstrading/views/home/home
```

I want all my URL's to look like this:

```
tactical_trading/toolstrading/home
```

So, if the page is for `about` it will look like this:

```
tactical_trading/toolstrading/about
```

I want to shorten all the URL's like my examples above.

Is that possible? Thank you.

Comment: Hey man, take a look at this: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/modrewrite-tips-tricks/
and this: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_rewrite-variables-cheatsheet/

It's very easy to understand ! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Comment: Can you post your attempt at solving this?